# Galactic Civilizations of Space Age Animals

Tags: society, civilization

I'm writing a story in which a bored god comes across the Milky Way and decides to create a space civilization to 'bring peace' to the chaos between the already existing space civilizations that exist.

So the bored god goes to the Earth, ignores the humans and decides to pick another species for uplift. But instead of picking just one, it decides to pick couple thousand individuals of several different species of animals (crocodiles, hawks, raccoons, elephants and sharks) and grants them human-level intelligence with its 'divine' powers. It brings them to another Earth-like planet, gives them space-level technology, tells them the goal of 'bringing peace' to the galaxy and leaves to watch the game unfold.

Assume they can communicate with an English-like language using the technology that they were given.

So the question is how would this coalition of space-age animals even start to achieve their goal. If this question seems a bit too broad, I'm more concerned about the day to day activities and the lack of culture. I assume a caste-based structure would probably arise.

Edit: The question is what direction would the society of this coalition end up as?

The technology is powered by handwavium so they have basic telekinetic powers to offset the lack of hands.

I want to say these animals feel indebted to their uplifter and would try to focus on achieving their end goal.

Comment: Excuse me, but I can't see what's your actual question here.

Comment: Lack of **hands** will be a serious detriment, as will their quadrupedal forms.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to have a coalition of 3 carnivores a animal known for stealing things and a huge walking piece of meat. The results of this would be of course varied. How devoted are the animals to the cause? How are the carnivores fed? Will they desire the flesh of their comrades? How do the animals make things without hands? How do they operate technology? How much can the technology help them? Can they have extra hands and such? Some of these things will be very important. What does each race bring to the table? As far as I see it now, raccoons are clear rulers. Elephants are slaves

Comment: @Molot I hope I cleared up the question a bit.

Comment: If you haven't watched [Zootopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zootopia) yet, please do it.

Comment: Way too broad.  Way too opinion-based.  We're willing to help, but this is writing about 50% of your story for you.  Stack Exchange sites are for asking specific questions to get specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

As unusual the premise of the question and scenario is - I would attempt to approach it as logically as possible.

Intelligence is still a hot area of debate - what actually is it and how physiologically does it manifest? You could argue humans are intelligent, but why? The common answer is we have large brains, however dolphins do to, yet they did not make cities. Also, by volume and weight a typical whale has a brain much larger than ours too, so is it smarter? Is it perhaps the brain to body ratio instead - but then a mouse has a brain to body ratio almost ten times ours, so it is still in contention what physically and physiologically causes 'intelligence'.

One argument is our 'intelligence' is actually more the evolving pathways in our brains caused both by evolutionary and education-induced influences, ie. 'software' instead of 'hardware'. There is a major portion of Brain Sciences devoted to this subject, however if this is true then we are intelligent only because of the people before us teaching us about the world we are in, giving us language (that they learnt), and providing us with capabilities which allows us to pass this on to our children.

This definition of intelligence has more relevance to your story: we are actually not defined by what we are, but who came before us, what they taught us, and what we teach our kids.

Physiologically all animals on earth are actually quite similar, the variance in the Animal Kingdom genetically is less than 0.1%, so it could be argued given similar capabilities and backgrounds, your cluster of animals are actually the same. If, as you say, they are 'intelligent', then this means they have knowledge, education, the means to communicate clearly, they have traditions, science, culture and arts, they have wisdom passed from their parents, and the ability to pass this all on to the next generation.

And therein lies your answer.

'Peace' is an idea that has evolved and passed through the generations and communicated throughout societies through the ages. If your animals have the wisdom to see that and can coexist peacefully themselves, this is an example that can be taught to all future children of the galaxy. The key has always been, and will always be, our children.